# How to reload a Python variable in an HTML page through Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask

so I'm trying to do something pretty basic.
I have a Python APP which selects a random item in a list. Let's say like this:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import random

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def homepage():
    def generator():
        first_list = ['list_item1', 'list_item2', 'list_item3']
        variable = random.choice(first_list) 
        return variable

    variable = generator()
    return render_template('index.html', variable=variable)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()

app.run(port=4995)
```

And so then I have my index.html page:

```
<body>
<h1>{{ variable }}</h1>

</body>
```

So this works. When I open the index.html page I get to see either list_item1, list_item2 or list_item3.

But now, what I need to do is to create a button/function to only refresh this exact variable, instead of reloading the whole page. So that only the text changes when the function from the app randomly selects a new item in the list.

And... I can't find how to do that. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Use ajax, you could use _jquery_, see [Flask: AJAX with jQuery](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/).

Answer (score -1):

Feels like you want to create a AJAX call to another isolated method that will run to get the number. So, create another function, create a AJAX call to it and update the element.